# Is tomcat = apache (or other web server) + JavaEE?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, webserver, httpserver

So I understand there are two kinds of servers, first kind is web server (or http server) such as nginx, apache, caddy, another kind is app server, such as tomcat, undertow. I just wonder if a java app server equals a general web server plus a j2ee environment? Or maybe things are not so simple and the app server did a lot of stuff besides just mixing the java environment?

Comment: Have you read through [the project introduction](http://tomcat.apache.org/)? If so, what specific question do you have? Although Tomcat (and all other servlet containers) do have a built-in web server, you usually use it behind a reverse proxy powered by a dedicated web server (nginx, Apache, IIS).

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet container, not a "full" J2EE server.

Answer (score 1):

Http server only implements the`Http` standard:it means accepting a `Http request` and sending a `Http response`.
supporting for php and other languages added via plugins to it(apache and so on).
A raw Http server only support static resources nothing else but statics.

But in java EE world Http server have to implement java EE specifications too.
java EE is a set of specifications.

If Http server implements all specifications we have `application server` like **glassfish**.

If Http server only implements servlet and JSP specifications we have   `servlet container` (also called web server in general)like **apache tomcat**(from apache foundation.it's not apache web server.its another server),**jetty** from eclipse foundation.

Any java compatible server is a raw Http server plus some implemented specification.

Answer (score 1):

As a seasoned Java developer, the assertion that Tomcat is the same as a web server plus a J2EE environment is irksome, because there are significant [differences between Tomcat and Apache](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Tomcat-vs-Apache-HTTP-Server-Whats-the-difference) in terms of how they are optimized, the role they play in a modern architecture and even how they are physically installed.

**You may be right...**

Having said that, your assertion may actually be correct. From the standpoint of a beginner, someone new to server-side programming, it's not completely wrong to think of Tomcat as being just a web server with a bunch of magical powers added to it, namely the various Java based APIs [Java EE/Jakarta EE](https://www.theserverside.com/news/252470565/Eclipse-completes-enterprise-Java-move-with-Jakarta-EE-8) builds into it.

**Apache and Tomcat in practice**

Tomcat does handle http based requests, and it can server files if it needs to, so it can do double duty. So from a simple standpoint, it's not totally wrong to think of Tomcat like that. Just remember that in modern architectures, the role of [Tomcat](https://www.theserverside.com/definition/Tomcat) and the Apache HTTP server are very different.

**Three tiered architecture**

Here's a look at how the two play together in a three tiered architecture:

[image: Three tiered architecture]